# Unable to Communicate from server to other servers after migrating from existing firewall to new firewall

Tags: routing, firewall, networking, arp

In our existing environment we had migrated old firewall with new firewall after this activity . we had faced connectivity issue . From servers unable to reach other servers . Post clearing ARP table we are able to connect . Here i don't understand  how ARP table clearing resolved this issue . throw some light here .

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

ARP maps (local) IP addresses to their MAC addresses. So, if you swap a device, reusing its IP address, incoming L2 frames are addressed incorrectly and subsequently ignored by the new device. Flushing the ARP cache requires a source device to run a new ARP request round and maps the IP address to its new MAC.

Comment: The system algorithm has identified the question as possible spam. I just do not see it.